# Caasandra join new seed in cluster when old seed nodes got destroyed/terminated

Tags: cassandra

I have simple cassandra cluster, 1 seed and 2 node.

I understand from redundancy purpose there should be two node, but my question is, "**for some reason if all my seed nodes got deleted, how to create and new seed node and make it join my running cluster**".

Comment: Deleted means, you removed or decommissioned right?

Comment: You should be able to change any node as a seed node by shutting it down and adding the IP to the seed list. Nothing special there. Make sure the seed list is consistent. Really only used for startup/bootstrapping nodes. Should be fine to simply change the list and restart.

Comment: if you have recent version of Cassandra, you don't even need to shut node down to add seeds - there is `nodetool reloadseeds` command: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsReloadSeeds.html

Comment: @JimWartnick the point is to start the server we need seed server's ip, and here seed server is destroyed, so how to do that and also get existing cluster details.

Comment: Assuming you have at least one node that survives (doesn't have to be a seed), simply add the node's IP to the seed list and it becomes a seed node. You don't need the node that was destroyed at all (as long as the RF > 1 and nodes are in sync (i.e. no missing data)). So if you had, say, a 3 node cluster and node 1 was the only seed. If node 1 was distroyed/lost, simply change the cassandra.yaml on the other nodes to have the seed list point to any remaining node and you're done. Either restart cassandra or, as stated above, use nodetool to reload the seeds.

Comment: Thanks for this information @JimWartnick, this is what I was looking for. If you will, please write it as answer and I will marked it as done for future references.

Comment: Thanks @AlexOtt for `nodetool reloadseeds`, didn't knew about it. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have at least one node that survives (doesn't have to be a seed), simply add the node's IP to the seed list and it becomes a seed node. You don't need the node that was destroyed at all (as long as the RF > 1 and nodes are in sync (i.e. no missing data)). So if you had, say, a 3 node cluster and node 1 was the only seed. If node 1 was distroyed/lost, simply change the cassandra.yaml on the other nodes to have the seed list point to any remaining node and you're done. Either restart cassandra or, as stated above, use nodetool to reload the seeds.